# Problemas al leer datos de un repositorio en una APIRest

Tags: api, entity-framework, rest

Tengo un problema con un Repositorio que no consigo ver el fallo

```
#region Operations
    // Generamos la consulta del Store Procedure
        querySP = $"CAll sp_APIRest_Expenses_GetAllByYear('{User.ID}',{Year});";

    // Ejecuamos la consulta del Store Procedura
        expenses_FromStoreProcedure = _repositoryViewExpenses.GetFromDatabaseWithQuery(querySP, new object[] { });

        // Comprovamos si hay respuesta, si la hay, devolvemos, sino indicamos del error
            if (expenses_FromStoreProcedure != null && expenses_FromStoreProcedure.Any())
            {
                viewExpenses xorra = expenses_FromStoreProcedure.First();

                List<viewExpenses> Listaxorra = expenses_FromStoreProcedure.ToList();

                returnGetExpenses = new ResultExpensesController()
                {
                    Id              = 1,
                    Result          = true,
                    ListExpenses    = expenses_FromStoreProcedure.ToList<viewExpenses>()
                };
            }
            else
            {
                returnGetExpenses = new ResultExpensesController()
                {
                    Id      = -3,
                    Result  = false,
                    Message = "Cannot find Vacaciones list"
                };
            }
```

Tengo ese IF dentro de un Try-Catch

en dicho try pasa por la funcion:

```
if (expenses_FromStoreProcedure != null && expenses_FromStoreProcedure.Any())
```

Cuando llega a:

```
viewExpenses xorra = expenses_FromStoreProcedure.First();
```

Me recoge bien los datos como muestro aqui

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PERO Cuando llega a esta linea:

```
List<viewExpenses> Listaxorra = expenses_FromStoreProcedure.ToList();
```

me falla

y el exception me indica:

```
Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por si os sirve de ayuda, este es el StackTrace:

> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetFieldValue(Int32 index, Boolean checkNull)
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 i)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactory.Create(DbDataReader dataReader)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.<_TrackEntities>d__17`2.MoveNext()
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>   at General.App.Agregates.Expenses.Services.ExpensesService.GetAllExpensesByYear(AuthorizedUserDTO User, Int32 Year) in C:\Projects\Optimissa\intranet-apirest\Optimissa.Intranet.API.Domain\Agregates\Expenses\Services\ExpensesService.cs:line 117

COMO ES POSIBLE QUE PASE POR EL .ANY() *que indica si hay algun contenido o no*, que me recoja el 1º elemento, pero al intentar pasarlo a una lista, me falle indicandome que el **DATA IS NULL**?

Comment: tu consulta se esta ejecutando cuanto pasas a ToList() por loque la validacion anterior no tiene ninguna validez //if (expenses_FromStoreProcedure != null && expenses_FromStoreProcedure.Any()) . Ahora alguna propiedad de tu objeto declarado esta recibiendo un valor null, esto es a una propiedad no nuleable la consulta le quiere establecer un valor nulo.

Comment: Pero... al pasar por el Any, n estoy haciendo que se ejecute la consulta para comprobar si contiene datos?? El any no sirve precisamente para eso? A demas... antes tengo el First, que si que recibe datos... no se ha ejecutado la consulta hay?  Y si me dices que estoy ejecutando la consulta 3 veces... como que las 2 primeras traen datos y la del ToList() no?   Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Ahora leyendo más atentamente tu comentario... dices que la consulta me trae algún campo nulo y que en el objeto en el que lo parseo es no nuleable y de hay el fallo? Luego compruebo bien todos los tipos d todos los campos para descartar eso, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Al final con los comentarios de Miguel Zarate he encontrado el problema

realmente he ejecutado la consulta 3 veces:

1. En el .Any() (que como tenia contenido ha pasado)
2. En el .First() (que como tenia contendo y el primer registro "encajava" con mi modelo, al hacer el parseo, "colaba")
3. En el ToList() AQUI es donde me fallaba, porque:

porque en el ToList yo estaba haciendo un parseo de TODOS LOS REGISTROS a mi clase: viewExpenses

Como dice Miguel Zarate, alguno de los registros, tenia campos en Nulo

para solventarlo he tenido que

1. Arreglar la clase viewExpenses asegurandome que permitia algunos valores Nulos
2. Arreglar el Mapping de la classe y asegurarme que los campos requeridos eran los correctos
3. Arreglar algunos datos de la BBDD para que fueran del tipo valido y con un valor correcto